# php : how to join 2 varibale and use that for one variable?

Tags: php, variables

```
$x = 1;


if (isset($locats))
    {
    foreach ($locats as $l)
        {
        ${"variable$x"} = new LatLng(['lat' => $l['google_map_lat'], 'lng' => $l['google_map_lng']]);

        ${"marker$x"} = new Marker([
            'position' =>$variable."$x"  ,
            'title' => $l['name'],
        ]);



        $x++;
        }
    }
```

i want join 2 varibale and use that in one variable!

in :

```
 'position' =>$variable."$x"  ,
```

i want set $variable1 and in next time $variable2 and .... for position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), like this:

```
$variable = "variable" . $x;
```

And use it like this:

```
$$variable // would give $variable1, $variable2 etc.
```